# add datatable in pytorch tensorboard

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I want to add training and validation loss to tensorboard as well as the result of test set.

I can't find add datatable in tensorboard.

Is the effort to add a data table to the tensor board meaningless?

Then let me know the alternative.